# Set custom typeface on Hint, TextInputLayout

Tags: android, xamarin, textinputlayout

I'm trying to set a custom typeface on the `Hint` of a `TextInputLayout`. Therefore I'm using a custom subclass of `TextInputLayout` with a custom property `MyHint`. This property setter should format the text and set the `FormattedText` but it doesn't work.

If I simply set the `FormattedHint` property it also doesn't format. Does anyone why these approaches are failing?

Below you can see my custom class with property.

Example:

```
BaseTextInputLayout userNameInput = view.FindViewById<BaseTextInputLayout>(Resource.Id.myId);
userNameInput.MyHint = "My Custom hint text";
```

Class:

```
   public class BaseTextInputLayout: TextInputLayout
    {
        public string MyHint
        {
            get
            {
                return Hint;
            }
            set { 
                if (value != null)
                {
                    SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder(value);
                    builder.SetSpan(new CustomTypeFaceSpan("", Constants_Android.TYPEFACE_YOGA_MET_EVY_CUSTOMFONT), 0, builder.Length(), SpanTypes.InclusiveExclusive);
                    this.HintFormatted = builder;
                }
                else
                {
                    this.HintFormatted = null;
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to use:

```
userNameInput.Typeface = yourCustomTypeFace;
```

I don't see much benefit to your sub-class with this property,  though you could certainly do:

```
public class BaseTextInputLayout: TextInputLayout
{
    public string MyHint
    {
        get
        {
            return Hint;
        }
        set { 
            if (value != null)
            {
                this.Typeface = yourCustomTypeFace;
                this.Hint = value;
            }
            else
            {
                this.Hint = null;
            }
        }
    }
```